# When creating new CRM Dynamics custom activity entity, is the new activity associated with lead, opportunity, and account?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I'm interested in persisting the following information

- SMS messages
- Voice/Phone Call details (inbound/outbound)
- Website chat messages
- Facebook Messenger messages

in CRM Dynamics such that this information is immediately view-able for a given entity. (Reporting is a bonus) I understand that 1 way of accomplishing this task of persisting communication history within the CRM is to create a custom activity as described here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/custom-activities

However, I need some clarification on how the new activity is associated with leads, opportunities, and accounts. For example, is it possible to have an activity associated with a lead, but no opportunity, nor any matching accounts? At the same time, is it possible to have an activity that is associated with a lead, an opportunity, and an account?

How are end users of CRM Dynamics viewing these types of historical messages within the UI?

Perhaps the answer to this is that a lead can be associated with an opportunity, and thus activity related to a lead could indirectly be associated with an opportunity from that connection?

I tested this by creating a lead,creating activity for that lead, then converting that lead into an opportunity. In this case, the activity added to the lead entity was visible within the opportunity entity form. However, When I created activity within the opportunity entity form, this activity did Not lead to activity viewable within the lead entity form.

Do I need to always save activity to a lead entity then?
 This seems like the only method in order to ensure that custom activity is always visible regardless of where the lead/opportunity/account is in the lifecycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamics CRM has functionality as

1. Under Account if You create Opportunity, and for this Opp if you have a Activity it will be visibile under Account.
2. Now if you create Lead, you create activity under lead and when you qualify Lead, your lead will be converted to Opp and all your Activites will be carried to Opp.
3. One more case with Lead, You create a Lead, In this Lead you add Account (you already know for which Account you have a Lead). Now you create Activity under Lead, even though this lead is connected to Account, it's activities will not be shown in Account. After you qualify this Lead and converted to Opp, all your Activities under Lead (currently Opp) will be show in Account.

Summary: Creating Activities to Lead and then qualifying to Opp will show up in Opp, not the other way around. Imp is to have a overview on Account

Few Screenshots for Ref.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: So where would you save activity for a lead that is converted to opportunity? Under the lead?or under the opportunity?

Comment: Under lead I save activity

Comment: So your recommending that I save all history under the lead, even though lead may have been converted to opportunity? Correct?

Comment: No what I mean, until the time lead is active keep working on it creating activities, once lead is qualified and converted to opportunity work with opportunity creating/ updating activities (activities from lead will also be on opportunity) this is the normal cycle of lead and opportunity

Comment: You are pretty much saying two somewhat contradictory things at once: I'm interpreting you saying "Yes, save all activity under the lead even when lead is converted to opportunity since all activity under the lead will show for opportunity anyways" and your also saying "No, save all activity under the lead up until the time the lead is converted to an opportunity, at which time its best to save all Future activity under the opportunity only"  so which is it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion the second option mentioned in your last comment is the correct way.

Comment: @joey did it helped?? If it solved your issue would you please mark it as solved, it will helps others as well.